# AttributeError module 'tensorflow' has no attribute in python 3.7.6 MacOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run this program https://github.com/catthatcodes/car-damage-assessment
and currently, i am getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/vikrant/Downloads/Car/catthatcodes/app/app.py", line 7, in module

```
from pipeline import pipeline


graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Answer (score 2):

You should try changing your imports from `keras` to `tensorflow.keras`, as it seems like a Tensorflow version update caused the change.

Alternatively, you may downgrade your Tensorflow version to a one that is compatible with your current way of calling it.

The issue is detailed here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12783